# Редакторы e-mail и пр.

Tags: редактор, iframe, javascript

Каким образом работают редакторы в gmail (при составлении и редактировании писем), вконтакте при составлении заметок http://vk.com/notes?act=new и прочие подобные? Каким образом это можно сделать самому, может мануалы? Шаблоны, скрипты? В интернете ничего не нашёл на подобную тему. Заранее спасибо.

Там нет никаких textarea, работа производится в подгружаемом iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это называется desingMode. Воспользуйтесь [поиском](http://www.google.ru/search?source=ig&hl=ru&rlz=&q=%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80+designMode&btnG=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA+%D0%B2+Google).
Так-же могу предложить достаточно толковую [статью](http://xpoint.ru/know-how/WYSIWYG/TrueJavaScriptEditor).